# How can i select all element without one of specifc class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to select all element in the document, but not the element of one specific class in JQuery.

I need to active function ever but not when i put the mouse in one div class.

I try this:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "*:not(".class_name"), function(){});
```

but it don't work.

Comment: what are you really trying to do

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gLhCF/1/ - I don't think it works like you think

Comment: put the mouse in one DIV class, but what about children of this DIV? Couldn't you provide your relevant HTML code and what are you expecting exactly?! And at least, show some effort, don't post invalid code or open your console or etc... If your issue was just about syntax error, SO is not a debugging help desk, thank to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is correct but with wrong quotes combination.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", '*:not(".class_name")', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your class name inside single quote `' '` instead of double quotes `" "`:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "*:not('.class_name')", function(){});
// ---                              ^  add here ^ ^ you also need to add double quote here to close your selector
```